# Direct comparison of energy measurements for kids

Tags: energy, everyday-life, education, home-experiment

I am planning a few physics & science sessions in the woods with 14 year-olds. The theme for one of the sessions is *Energy*, and my aim is to show them how gravity, solar radiation, wind (air motion), organic decomposition (from farmyard manure) can produce energy, and how do the corresponding processes compare to each other.

For the case of gravity, I can easily make them set up a simple syphon. The water would need to be brought uphill from a small well, and this work (done by their muscles) transforms chemical energy into mechanical one. At this point I can introduce potential energy, in which form the work done is "stored", and show them how in the syphon the relative height of the source and sink of water allows us to calculate the work done, that is a measure of energy. This can be compared with the work needed to crack a walnut open by letting a certain stone fall over it, and the mechanism is the same, since the work is done by the gravitational field, it depends on mass and height of the stone, and it's calculated in the same way as for the syphon.

As for solar power, I can buy a solar phone charger, but how could I effectively compare a measurement, or any other "work done" with the previous two cases? What should I set up? If I burn a piece of paper by using a magnifying glass, I won't know how to estimate that energy and compare it.

For the manure I was thinking of making it warm up a certain volume of air (in a box or bag) and use the temperature difference to measure the energy transformed into heat.

I am stuck also for the wind (is there something I could do with a small turbine like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002MPDIGO/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_img?_encoding=UTF8&colid=22S8I47EZS1IB&coliid=IJRRE94UNGMW5)?) and possibly running water (I could perhaps buy a [micro hydro-generator](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00K74GPVM/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=22S8I47EZS1IB&coliid=I2LT8ZFFO0N8TT)?).

Any advice, suggestion, theoretical or practical would be very very appreciated!

Comment: I think that it is much easier to quantitatively compare two energies of the same type than to quantitatively compare energies of different types. So for gravitational potential energy, for example, you could probably arrange some simple demonstrations that the amount of energy scales with the height and mass of the object. As for comparing different types of energy (e.g., gravitational potential versus light), I think that I would just limit myself to just demonstrating that it is possible to convert one type to the other rather than trying to quantitatively show that energy  is conserved.

Comment: How much time, and more importantly, how much physics teaching experience do you have? If I remember correctly, the scope of what you are trying to do here requires about half a year or so in the physics classroom to work trough these concepts, understand force, work and energy conservation. There are several non-trivial pitfalls with these concepts and teaching them CORRECTLY is not easy. Do you know how to teach them correctly? Based on what you are trying to do it doesn't sound like you do. May I suggest something? Do a learning unit on a topic that you know on a professional level.

Comment: Thanks your comment. Could you please also give me some advice about the physics? I see that you think I am not prepared to teach these subject (in fact I am a unit developer for this project, therefore I will not teach it myself, but a physics teacher will). Could you please specify what makes you think so and what in my observations gives you this impression? I am not up for any polemics, but I think your opinion could really help. Thanks!